# Conditional Views exposed filters

Tags: 6, views

So, I have a view that has multiple exposed filters.  If someone selects one of the filter options, I need the rest of the exposed filters options to change dependent on what was selected in the first.
For example three of the filters are: instruction, video duration, learning level.

If a specific instructor is selected, the video duration and learning levels should change to shown only the videos of that instructor. (These are not based on taxonomy.)

I am using Drupal 6 and Views 6.x-2.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one module that I found that will do this work for me. Views hacks, selective views Filters: [Views Selective Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_filters_selective).